# ORA-12570: Network Session: Unexpected packet read error

Tags: oracle, .net-core, google-cloud-platform, odp.net, alpine-linux

we are getting ORA-12570: Network Session: Unexpected packet read error from our webapi written in .Net core 2.2. The API is hosted in Alpine Docker OS 3.11 in GCP using kubernetes. We are using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core version 2.19.60.

The intrenal error message we get is

Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-12570: Network Session: Unexpected packet read error ---> OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException (0x80004005): ORA-12570: Network Session: Unexpected packet read error ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (110): Operation timed out.

Per the website http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12570_tns_packet_reader_failure.htm, ORA-12570 occur due to listener configuration. IS that true? Also Let us know how if tracing works in linux for ODP.Net core.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

This is a generic error; it is not necessarily related to the Oracle Listener. The key here is "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (110): Operation timed out." This could be a lot of things; you really need to do [Oracle Net tracing](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql_net_tracing.htm) to determine what's going on. Could be that your client can't see the network at all, or that network latency or packet routing are not what they should be, or several other things.